Fullscreen menu disables the browser reload button
I'm trying to make a full screen burger menu. It all works, I just don't understand why if I try to reload the page using the browser button it doesn't work (the page isn't reloaded) while if I do it from the address bar it works.
Who can help me understand where I'm wrong? Thanks so much in advance.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Menu Hamburger Creativo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap');

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .hidden {
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .menuMainButton {
            position: fixed;
            top: 30px;
            right: 30px;
            background: none;
            border: none;
            font-size: 2em;
            color: #2c3e50;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 9998;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

        .menuMainButton:hover {
            transform: scale(1.3);
        }

        .menu-content {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            background-color: #ede6de;
            color: #282828;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            overflow-y: auto;
            z-index: 9997;
            font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        .menu-content.show {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }

        .sinistra {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-start;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .centro {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-start;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .destra {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-start;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            height: 100vh;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- MENÙ --> 
    <button class="menuMainButton" id="menuMainButton"><i class="bi bi-list" id="menuMainIcon"></i></button>

    <div class="menu-content" id="menu-content">
        <div class="container-fluid min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="row flex-fill">
                <div class="col-md-3 sinistra">
                    <p>Sinistra</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 centro p-5">
                    <p>Centro</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 destra p-3">
                    <p>Destra</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MENÙ / FINE--> 
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: yellow"><h1>Uno</h1></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: pink"><h1>Due</h1></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menuMainButton');
            const menuContent = document.getElementById('menu-content');
            const menuIcon = document.getElementById('menuMainIcon');

            menuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                menuContent.classList.toggle('show');
                if (menuContent.classList.contains('show')) {
                    menuIcon.classList.replace('bi-list', 'bi-x');
                    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // Disable scrolling when menu is open
                } else {
                    menuIcon.classList.replace('bi-x', 'bi-list');
                    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'; // Enable scrolling when menu is closed
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I have already tried to modify the body overflow both x and x, but I can't solve it.

I don't see how this could "refuse" a reload triggered by the browser button. Probably more likely that it reloads in the same state it is currently in, so that you don't really notice? What happens when you open browser dev tools, do you see a new request happen in there, when you reload?

And by "fullscreen" you don't actually mean anything that uses the Fullscreen API, but only something that covers the current viewport, correct?


Yes, I confirm that the page reloads in the same state it is in.
That's right, I have the "menu-content" div that covers the entire viewport.

